# Get another content type values in a content type

Tags: php, drupal-7, field

I have a content type called "websites" and in it I have `field_adres`. There are at least 10 of this type of node. What I want to do is to be able to get this field's values so that I can use it in a dropdown in another content type.

I have to use PHP, How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Entity reference (https://drupal.org/project/entityreference)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an Entity Reference field: reference fields from different content types. https://drupal.org/project/entityreference